# symfony installation with svn:externals

Tags: svn, symfony-1.4

I am trying to install symfony from subversion but when I try to commit, I have to login.

The steps I did:

```
$ svn co http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4 
$ svn pe symfony/
  entering http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4 and save
$ svn commit
```

(Authentication realm: http://svn.symfony-project.com:80 SVN).

I have no idea, what I should use as username and password. Is there a general login?

I appreciate any help. 
Thanks
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my fault in this post: [What's the benefits of "svn:externals"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377593/whats-the-benefits-of-svnexternals):

After 'svn pe symfony/' you have to type

```
$ svn commit -m "add externals"
```

instead of 'svn commit'. It works then, like I want it.

Answer (score 1):

To install symfony from svn, you just have to check out the symfony-project repository. Only the symfony developers team can commit on this repository and needs a username/password.

Did you follow these steps to install: [Practical symfony - Day 1: Starting up the Project](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01)

?

Comment: ... and exactly here is the "installing from Subversion ... recommended..."

"If you use Subversion, it is even better to use the svn:externals property to embed symfony into your project in the lib/vendor/ directory:

    $ svn pe svn:externals lib/vendor/"

But if you do it this way it does not work either.

Comment: Have you created a new svn repository for your project, as explained at the end?

Comment: No, I thought, it is not necessary, is it?

Comment: It is not mandatory but very useful :-). If you don't want to use a repository for your project, I think you just have to check out the symfony repository to install it: the first step you've done should be good enough.

Comment: That's not enough for me, because I want to ensure that I have always the newest version of symfony 1.4. But I finally found the solution, see answer below.